# Reversing all arrows without changing the place of any set

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrows, tikz-cd

Here is the code; I want to reverse its arrows without changing the place of any set:

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzcd}
    &  N_1 \ar{rd}{j_1}\\
    N\ar{ru}{i_1} \ar{r}{i_2}\ar{rd}[swap]{i_3} & N_2 \ar{r}{j_2} & N'\\
    & N_3 \ar{ru}[swap]{j_3}
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change the default arrow type with the option `arrows=<-` and no other change in the code for the diagram. I use the “modern” syntax for arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

A commutative diagram and its dual
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
  &  N_1 \ar[rd,"j_1"]\\
  N \ar[ru,"i_1"] \ar{r}{i_2} \ar[rd,"i_3"'] & N_2 \ar[r,"j_2"] & N'\\
  & N_3 \ar[ru,"j_3"']
\end{tikzcd}
\qquad
\begin{tikzcd}[arrows=<-]
  &  N_1 \ar[rd,"j_1"]\\
  N \ar[ru,"i_1"] \ar{r}{i_2} \ar[rd,"i_3"'] & N_2 \ar[r,"j_2"] & N'\\
  & N_3 \ar[ru,"j_3"']
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I change the default arrow type?

Comment: @Happy Doesn't the code show how? I just added the option `arrows=<-`. I added it for clarity, thanks for noting.

Comment: yeah sorry about that

Answer (score 3):

Here it is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzcd}
    & N_1 \ar{rd}{j_1}\\
    N\ar{ru}{i_1} \ar{r}{i_2}\ar{rd}[swap]{i_3} & N_2 \ar{r}{j_2} & N'\\
    & N_3 \ar{ru}[swap]{j_3}
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}

    \[ \begin{tikzcd}
    & N_1 \ar{dl}[swap]{i_1}\\
    N& N_2 \ar{l}{i_2} & N' \ar{ul}[swap]{j_1}\ar{l}{j_2}\ar{dl}{j_3} \\
    & N_3 \ar{ul}{i_3}
  \end{tikzcd} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]